# Python Implementing array as tree then implementing BFS

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, tree, breadth-first-search

I'm unsure how to implement the following problem. I have a 2D array that I need to turn into a tree where the value of each node is determined from the matrix, but I'm not sure how to implement the method of correctly creating the appropriate tree. Here's an example for clarification:

```
    Matrix:


 0[ 3.  1.]
 1[ 6.  4.]
 2[ 2.  0.]
 3[ 5.  3.]
 4[ 1.  6.]
 5[ 4.  2.]
 6[ 0.  5.]
 7[ 3.  1.]`
```

Using that matrix I would then create a tree where the children of any given node is determined by the numbers in it's row of the matrix. For example if I chose 7 to be the root, I would get:

```
           7
        3     1
      5  3   6  4
```

And would continue to build the tree until a zero is reached. Where I would then return the path to the 0. (The matrix can have more than 2 columns, generating more than 2 children per node)

I'm having trouble determining what the code to implement the tree generation would be, it seems like it would be some variation of breadth-first, but I'm unsure.

Comment: BFS and DFS are for _searching_ the graph, not for generating it.

Comment: Couldn't it be generated in the same manner? Rather than just searching and removing, I would be adding.

Comment: You have not shown what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the confusion stems from you asking about building a tree - that's not necessary, since you *already have the graph structured*. You have the links between each element in your matrix, and since it really isn't a tree (there are loops where a child can point to a parent if it were a tree) - it's already a graph.

Then it becomes a matter of applying a regular BFS and keeping track of the path for each step in your path while exploring:

```
# graph
m = {
    0: (3, 1),
    1: (6, 4),
    2: (2, 0),
    3: (5, 3),
    4: (1, 6),
    5: (4, 2),
    6: (0, 5),
    7: (3, 1),
}

# seed queue
queue = [(7, [])]

# bfs
while (queue):
    idx, path = queue.pop(0)
    path.append(idx)

    for n_idx in m[idx]:
        # check if the next node would be a 0
        if not n_idx:
            print(path)
            queue = []
            break

        # append the next index and a copy of the current path object    
        queue.append((n_idx, list(path)))
```

Comment: This helped a ton, and definitely put me on the right track. The only thing I'm not sure of is how I would create the graph generically from a generic matrix (not necessarily with the same number of rows and columns as another call). Something along the lines of  "if matrix has row i, create row i using matrix[i][j] as column entry "

Comment: This solution is based on an arbitrary number of rows and columns, so as long as the matrix is defined as in the example, it'll work. Since you're loading the starting row into the BFS (when the queue is created), and the inner part of the bfs is a for-loop iterating over the columns in that row, the number of rows or columns can vary freely. You can also add a `visited´ flag for each row to avoid visiting the same row multiple times (if you have a circular graph you'd have one exploration going around in this case).

Comment: Sorry, I think I was a bit vague with my description. What I meant to say was the generating of the graph in your example uses a specific matrix (the one I used in the example). However in my program I'll be feeding it a matrix that is defined by calculations done earlier in the program. So what I'm looking for is a way to say m = {

Comment: So what I'm looking for is a way to generically generate the graph like so: m = {0: (0, 1, ...,M(where M is num columns in matrix)), 1:(0, 1, ..M), ...N(0, 1,...M)}. The program would therefore use BFS on any MxN matrix it was given, where M and N could be different from a previous M and N.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, as long as the graph is formatted in the same way as in my example (i.e. a key that has a list of indices its linked to), it'll work properly for any MxN (where each row could have a different count of N's as well). If you're asking about _how to generate the matrix_, the question doesn't contain any information regarding that.

Comment: For example: if I knew that my matrix was always going to have 2 rows and 2 columns I could do                                                                        def function(matrix)                                                                                    m = {
    0: (matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1]),
    1: (matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1]),
    }    return m                                             However, if I then fed the function another matrix that was 3x3, I would only end up with the first 2 rows and 2 columns if the above were my function. I'm unsure how to fix that.

Comment: Isnt that the same as `m = {}, idx = 0, for r in matrix: m[idx] = matrix[idx]` ? But if you're using it directly, you really don't need the dictionary (if the key is just the row number anyway, you can just do matrix[..][..] instead of going through `m` as a dictionary), just giving the above matrix directly should work.